# Prove $(1 + \sqrt n)^{2/n} \leq (1 + 1/\sqrt n )^2$ for all natural $n$.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove $(1 + \sqrt n)^{2/n} \leq (1 + 1/\sqrt n )^2$ for all natural $n$

I may or may not have to use Bernoulli's Inequality in this question.

I tried using Bernoulli's inequality on both sides of the question but I got nothing so far.
Am I even on the right path?

Comment: If you raise both sides to the $n/2$ power, Bernoulli's Inequality applies directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler than that.  Taking each side to the $n/2$th power, your inequality is equivalent to

$$1+\sqrt n \le \left(1+{1\over\sqrt n}\right)^n$$

But the right hand side expands as

$$\left(1+{1\over\sqrt n}\right)^n=1+{n\over\sqrt n}+\text{more terms, all positive}$$